# How does kubernetes NFS client provisioner HA works?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am new to kubernetes. We have a requirement to create a NFS mount point and provision it in kubernetes cluster using nfs-subdir-external-provisioner

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner#readme

On high level, i understand that this nfs-client-provisioner acts as an interface between underlying client (installed in K8s worker nodes) and kubernetes cluster. The plan is to create single mount point location and provision it inside kubernetes. How does the nfs-client-provisioner works for single and multiple replicas? Will it distribute the load across pods? In our case, it is single mount. How does the multiple nfs-client-provisioner works for single mount point.

Comment: NFS is readwritemany and can be used from different nodes and pods. The issue what i see here is, that NFS cannot handle read write locks on files for multiple pods (if I'm not wrong). You probably have to handle file locks by yourself or let them work with different directories. Btw. For NFS you do not need the external subdir provisioner. Just a NFS server would be enough. This one does not need to run inside the cluster, but has to be reachable. In case you install and maintain your cluster by yourself, you have to install nfs-client on the nodes itself. Does this information help you?

Comment: Or maybe i should ask, what is the main scenario you try to cover? The provisioner works just as a proxy for the NFS server, which is still needed.

Comment: The provisioned shared storage is attached to application PODs through StorageClass and PVCs. The application PODs will create small files continuously and write into NFS shared storage, and it also handles read/write locks. 
My question is, do we need multiple provisioner instances for HA? How does this HA works?
Thanks for the response!!!

Comment: If there's just one NFS server behind it, then there is no real HA anyway even if you setup the provisioner as high available. Maybe i don't see the big picture yet...